# My Python code gets skipped?

Tags: python, ftp

I wrote a small textbased game in Python 2.7, that can patch itself via FTP.
When i start my launcher the game startes without patching, what do I wrong?

```
import hotseat
import ftplib as ftp


#connect to FTP server
ftp = ftp.FTP("...", "...", "...")
ftp.cwd ("recent_version")
print "Connection to server succesfull"

#Patch Characters
f = open("chars.py", "wb")
ftp.retrbinary ("RETR chars.py", f.write)
f.close
print "Retrieved character data"

#Patch Hotseat
f = open("hotseat.py", "wb")
ftp.retrbinary ("RETR hotseat.py", f.write)
f.close
ftp.quit()

print "Retrieved game data"
print

hotseat.hotseat()
```

When I run the script I get the output of the hotseat module ("Welcome to hotseat mode") but no Warning or "Connected to server"...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This won't work *anyway*. Python loads your Python file *first*, then runs the code. Rewriting the file won't update what code Python runs, it already read the file.

Comment: Could I write a file then, wich overwrites the files and then calls the launcher file?

Comment: Your launcher could load a *separate* file from FTP, then import that file. Provided that file wasn't imported before loading a new version, the newest version will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding an version.txt file to the directory.
The launcher checks if the content of the local version.txt matches the hosted versionfile.
If they don't match the game won't start until the user uses the updater.py eich downloads the newer files.